# Google Geochart: custom display name using lat/long markers and both values

Tags: google-visualization

I have a Google Geochart with the following columns:

```
// Lat, Long, Value 1, Value 2
[-22.764042,  -43.39921  , 2.86, 1],
[-22.755635,  -43.460325 , 3.70, 2],
[-22.912897,  -43.200295 , 0.50, 1],
[-22.805776 , -43.37292 ,  6.67, 2],
[-23.532905 , -46.63952 ,  33.33, 5]
// ...many rows
```

I've checked the other answers, but they don't work here.

I **can't use those value columns** to display a label because both are important on this chart.

I **can't use addresses** instead of lat/long because it is really, really slow to load all markers (and they are many in the real chart).

I've **tried to apply formatters** to solve this, but it seems they are overridden by the library which display a "beautiful"coordinate (*22º76'4042"S,  43º39'921"W* instead of *-22.764042,  -43.39921*)

Is there any way I could load the chart markers with coordinates, but **display a custom label on their tooltips**?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add a "string" type column after the lat/long columns to give the data point a label for the tooltips:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number', 'Latitude');
data.addColumn('number', 'Longitude');
data.addColumn('string', 'Label');
data.addColumn('number', 'Value 1');
data.addColumn('number', 'Value 2');

data.addRows([
    [-22.764042, -43.39921, 'Foo', 2.86, 1],
    [-22.755635, -43.460325, 'Bar', 3.70, 2],
    [-22.912897, -43.200295, 'Baz', 0.50, 1],
    [-22.805776, -43.37292, 'Cad', 6.67, 2],
    [-23.532905, -46.63952, 'Qud', 33.33, 5]
]);
```

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/GKmm5/